# Find .dll 'SP = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client'

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, development

I need to add project .dll:

```
using SP = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
```

where this .dll? I use VS 2015.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should not be at the machine if SharePoint is not installed on your machine. You can add it from Nuget

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll

If SharePoint is installed on your machine, you can find this `.dll` at following location

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI
```

Comment: Install-Package : Could not install package 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll 15.0.4420.1017'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETF
ramework,Version=v4.5.2', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, cont
act the package author.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll -Version 15.0.4420.1017

Comment: Change target framework to 4.5 from project properties

Comment: Install-Package : Could not install package 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll 15.0.4420.1017'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETF
ramework,Version=v4.5', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contac
t the package author.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll -Version 15.0.4420.1017

Comment: I have just tested. It's working on my machine. Don't know what went wrong on your machine

Comment: Isn't work, use 2 server SharePoint, some this errors: Install-Package : Could not install package 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll 15.0.4420.1017'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETF ramework,Version=v4.5', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contac t the package author.

Comment: Then copy the dll from mentioned directory and add reference

Comment: Thanks, its work this https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SharePoint.Client/